# How to create a dropdown menu in a UIControlViewCell in iOS, Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to create a dropdown menu in a UIControlViewCell in iOS Objective-C?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this one:
https://github.com/BijeshNair/NIDropDown
It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no thing such as drop down in iOS but what you can do is use UIPickerPiew on click of textbox field. you can call this pickerview in place of your normal keyboard